# c# MainWindowHandle always zero

Tags: c#, process, handle

I read a few threads about the MainWindowHandle but i couldnt find a solution for my problem, i'm starting a gui application and want to get the MainWindowHandle through the process object, but the handle value is always zero if i'm not going to wait with thread.sleep() until the gui is loaded. i'm also tried to use WaitForInputIdle but it didnt help at all.

```
process.Start();

process.WaitForInputIdle(1000);
while (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
     Thread.Sleep(100);
}
// do something with the handle
```

he is never leaving the while, if i'm replacing the waitforinputidle with a normal thread.sleep he gets the handle right.

to put it in simply words: i only want to continue with my code if i get a handle != zero but i dont want to wait a static time for this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value stored in MainWindowHandle is cached. Add a process.Refresh() within your loop to invalidate that value:

```
while (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    process.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: thats the solution, thanks. but how role is the waitforinputidle playing ? reading the msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle.aspx it should help with the problem that the handle is "not ready"

Comment: @dontcare, it's not entirely clear to me how effective WaitInputIdle() actually is.  We can only go off what the documentation on the method tells us - that is, it blocks until the child is in an idle state.  This leads one to believe that being idle means that the child has a `MainWindowHandle`, but, as you can see from your original encounter with this method, this is not entirely accurate.